# jQuery - Passing Information from one page to another using (localStorage.setItem) and (localStorage.getItem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to pass 4 variables from one page to another using jQuery for some reason is not working for me.

This is what I have:

Page 1

```
//After clicking in the button that submit the form in page 1
$("#undefined-652").click(function () { 
   var first_nameV = $("input[name='first_name']").val();
   var last_nameV = $("input[name='last_name']").val();
   var emailV = $("input[name='email']").val();
   var phoneV = $("input[name='phone']").val();
   
   //to set null in value
   localStorage.setItem("first_name_val","");
   localStorage.setItem("last_name_val","");
   localStorage.setItem("email_val","");
   localStorage.setItem("phone_val","");
   
   //to set value
   localStorage.setItem("first_name_val",first_nameV);
   localStorage.setItem("last_name_val",last_nameV);
   localStorage.setItem("email_val",emailV);
   localStorage.setItem("phone_val",phoneV);
  });
```

Page 2

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var v_first_name = localStorage.getItem("first_name_val");
   var v_last_name = localStorage.getItem("last_name_val");
   var v_email = localStorage.getItem("email_val");
   var v_phone = localStorage.getItem("phone_val");

   $("#first_21").val(v_first_name);
   $("#last_21").val(v_last_name);
   $("#input_22").val(v_email);
   $("#input_23_full").val(v_phone);
});
```

For some unknown reason, those fields are empty when the page load. Any advice or tip will be appreciated.

Comment: So `#first_21` is an input field? Do you see the values in the console when you do `console.log(localStorage);`

Comment: Yes, they are input fields, and yes, I can see in the console the value of all variables... Not sure what's happening here...

Comment: Does `console.log(v_first_name, v_last_name, v_email, v_email);` show you want you expect? Does `console.log($("#first_21").length, $("#last_21").length, $("#input_22").length, $("#input_23_full").length);` all show that it found one element? You need to debug

Comment: When I run console.log(localStorage); I get all the expected values but when I run

console.log($("#first_21").length, $("#last_21").length, $("#input_22").length, $("#input_23_full").length);

I get: 0 0 0 0

Comment: So there you go.... you do not find your inputs. Hard to set the values of inputs it can not find.

Comment: Show your HTML for the inputs

Comment: for example this is the first name field:

`<input type="text" id="first_21" name="q21_fullName[first]" class="form-textbox validate[required] form-validation-error" data-defaultvalue="" size="10" value="" data-component="first" aria-labelledby="label_21 sublabel_21_first" required="">`

I forgot to mention this is a jotform embedded in the page...

Comment: Edit your question.... add the code

Comment: Well I have zero cle what every that form thing is. My guess is you need to see if they have an event listener that tells you that the form has loaded. I am not going to read their api.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time... I will keep troubleshooting here trying to find a solution...